# SACAR GRUPO DE ISLAS CON FECHAS CONSECUTIVAS EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

buenos dias compañeros,

tengo un problema y es que yo tengo un grupo de fechas (inicial y final) y necesito sacar por grupos aquellos que tienen fecha consecutiva, la fecha final es la misma inicial del siguiente registro

adjunto la imagen de lo que se quiere. tambien el set de datos, para ver

```
ITEM_NAME           FECHA_INICIO_DIFERIDA   FECHA_FIN_DIFERIDA  DIFERIDA_OIL
CHICHIMENE SW-64:1  18-Jan-2021             20-Jan-2021          985.56
CHICHIMENE SW-64:1  20-Jan-2021              1-Feb-2021          6669.57
CHICHIMENE SW-64:1  1-Feb-2021              15-Feb-2021          8061.06
CHICHIMENE SW-64:1  8-May-2021               2-Jun-2021          15934.27
CHICHIMENE SW-64:1  12-Jun-2021             14-Jun-2021          1425.03
CHICHIMENE SW-64:1  19-Jun-2021             19-Jun-2021          100.03
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda, no pongo el query porque me da pena lo que hecho, en manejado row_number con restas, pero no me dan, restando, pero llega en un punto que no da

Comment: En realidad sí deberías escribir en la pregunta la consulta que tenés hasta el momento, para que sea más sencillo ayudarte. Recordá que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. Leé [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo podría ser la siguiente:

Primero utilizamos la función de ventana `LAG()` para determinar si hay continuidad entre la `FECHA_FIN_DIFERIDA` de la fila anterior y la `FECHA_INICIO_DIFERIDA` de la fecha actual (habrá continuidad si ambas fechas son iguales). Si hay continuidad, la columna `continuidad` tendrá un cero, sino tendrá un 1.

En la primer fila de cada grupo (en este caso el grupo son todas las filas con el mismo `ITEM_NAME`), al utilizar `LAG()` retornará nulo, ya que no existe una fila anterior con dicho `ITEM_NAME`, y la columna `continuidad` contendrá un 1 (si quisieramos que contenga un cero, solo hay que comparar utilizando el `!=` e intercambiar los valores de `THEN` y `ELSE` (pero de esta forma los `GRUPO_ISLA` comenzarán desde cero en lugar de desde 1).

Luego lo que hacemos es utilizar la función ventana `SUM()` para calcular la suma acumulada de cada grupo (`ITEM_NAME`), entonces la filas consecutivas tendrán el mismo número (ya que sumo cero), y cuando no haya fila consecutiva se incrementará en 1.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *,
                    CASE WHEN FECHA_INICIO_DIFERIDA = LAG(FECHA_FIN_DIFERIDA) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NAME ORDER BY FECHA_INICIO_DIFERIDA)
                         THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS continuidad
             FROM t)
             
SELECT *,
       SUM(continuidad) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM_NAME ORDER BY FECHA_INICIO_DIFERIDA) AS GRUPO_ISLA
FROM cte;
```

**Salida** (con los datos de ejemplo de la pregunta):

| ITEM_NAME | FECHA_INICIO_DIFERIDA | FECHA_FIN_DIFERIDA | DIFERIDA_OIL | continuidad | GRUPO_ISLA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CHICHIMENE SW-64:1 | 2021-01-18 | 2021-01-20 | 985.56 | 1 | 1 |
| CHICHIMENE SW-64:1 | 2021-01-20 | 2021-02-01 | 6669.57 | 0 | 1 |
| CHICHIMENE SW-64:1 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-15 | 8061.06 | 0 | 1 |
| CHICHIMENE SW-64:1 | 2021-05-08 | 2021-06-02 | 15934.27 | 1 | 2 |
| CHICHIMENE SW-64:1 | 2021-06-12 | 2021-06-14 | 1425.03 | 1 | 3 |
| CHICHIMENE SW-64:1 | 2021-06-19 | 2021-06-19 | 100.03 | 1 | 4 |

Comment: muchas gracias nachospiu me sirvio mucho la ayuda, ya mas o menos entiendo el tema de brechas o islas

Comment: De nada @sadidmontero!!! Me alegro que te haya sido util mi query.